# ../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/ throwing Error failed to Failed to compile application

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-run

I created and ran `Flutter` projects. but today, while I'm creating new `Flutter` projects. I'm getting this kind of error when doing `flutter run`, I updated my flutter with the latest version. What went wrong with this

```
flutter 3.13.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d211f42860 (2 weeks ago) • 2023-10-25 13:42:25 -0700
Engine • revision 0545f8705d
Tools • Dart 3.1.5 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

> I created an issue Flutter on GitHub - [issue link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138214)

the error I'm getting,

```
Checking for wireless devices...

[1]: macOS (macos)
[2]: Chrome (chrome)
Please choose one (or "q" to quit): 2
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:56:3: Error: Getters, setters and methods can't be declared to be
'const'.
Try removing the 'const' keyword.
  const CounterPagePlaceholder({
  ^^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:54:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'Placeholder' is missing
implementations for these members:
 - Placeholder.CounterPagePlaceholder
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class Placeholder extends StatelessWidget {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:56:9: Context: 'Placeholder.CounterPagePlaceholder' is defined here.
  const CounterPagePlaceholder({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart:1238:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'color'.
            color: Color(0xCF8D021F),
            ^^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:54:7: Context: The class 'Placeholder' has a constructor that takes
no arguments.
class Placeholder extends StatelessWidget {
      ^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:57:5: Error: Super-initializer formal parameters can only be used in
generative constructors.
Try removing 'super.'.
    super.key,
    ^^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:58:5: Error: Field formal parameters can only be used in a
constructor.
Try removing 'this.'.
    this.color = const Color(0xFF455A64), // Blue Grey 700
    ^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:59:5: Error: Field formal parameters can only be used in a
constructor.
Try removing 'this.'.
    this.strokeWidth = 2.0,
    ^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:60:5: Error: Field formal parameters can only be used in a
constructor.
Try removing 'this.'.
    this.fallbackWidth = 400.0,
    ^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:61:5: Error: Field formal parameters can only be used in a
constructor.
Try removing 'this.'.
    this.fallbackHeight = 400.0,
    ^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:62:5: Error: Field formal parameters can only be used in a
constructor.
Try removing 'this.'.
    this.child
    ^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:66:15: Error: Final field 'color' is not initialized.
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor.
  final Color color;
              ^^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:69:16: Error: Final field 'strokeWidth' is not initialized.
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor.
  final double strokeWidth;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:77:16: Error: Final field 'fallbackWidth' is not initialized.
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor.
  final double fallbackWidth;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:85:16: Error: Final field 'fallbackHeight' is not initialized.
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor.
  final double fallbackHeight;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart:90:17: Error: Final field 'child' is not initialized.
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor.
  final Widget? child;
                ^^^^^
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             10.6s
Failed to compile application.
```

Comment: I caught error something like you when update on different flutter version. Seems like something broken on your flutter package project. Just download directly flutter from web and replace your flutter with newest from web. https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install